# Under the equivalence principle, does a bullet experience gravitational time dilation during acceleration?

Tags: time-dilation, equivalence-principle

Does the equivalence principle include gravitational time dilation for an accelerating object? A bullet accelerates in the barrel of a gun at 10^6 m/s^2.  If this acceleration was the gravity of a planet, it would have very significant gravitational time dilation. Does the bullet experience this gravitational time dilation under the equivalence principle?

Comment: Well, "it would have very significant gravitational time dilation" over time-- ie, if you remained on the planet. Bullets experience that dilation in a very short interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Gravitational time dilation is based on *potential*, not acceleration. The [clock postulate](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/clock.html) says that time dilation does not directly depend on acceleration, and this has been tested experimentally in particle accelerators to a high degree of accuracy. (Of course acceleration does have an indirect effect on time dilation, since it changes what inertial frame is considered "at rest".)

In an accelerating frame (like a rocket) there's a pseudo-potential which causes clocks at the front of the rocket to tick faster than clocks at the back. This is true even for a rigid rocket (where both clocks are accelerating at the same speed). When viewed from outside the rocket the difference is explained by the relativity of simultaneity -- the accelerated rocket observer has different surfaces of simultaneity than the unaccelerated "outside" observer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, but I wanted to add a note on magnitudes.

The formula for time dilation (first order only) is:

$\frac{dt'}{dt}\approx 1+\frac{gh}{c^2}$

Even if we approximate the bullet's motion (at the instant of firing) as acceleration through a constant gravity field with $g=10^6 \, m/s^2$ at $1\,m$ long (say in a rifle), because of the size of $c^2$ that only gives
$\approx 1+10^{-11}$ for the difference in time between the bullet chamber and the muzzle exit.