# Gravitational vs Inertial forces

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, equivalence-principle

In D'inverno's relativity book, it says that if we describe flat space using a general coordinate system, the equation of motion of a free particle would have terms involving the connection. Those terms would encode inertial forces. It then says that, to generalize this point of view to include gravity, gravity as well as inertial forces are to be described by the connection, but the metric can no longer be flat, the reason being that otherwise there would be no distinction between gravity and inertial forces. But my understanding was that this was the point of the equivalence principle: to treat gravity as an inertial force, since it doesn't depend on any properties of the body or its composition. What is the difference between gravity and inertial forces, at least from the book's point of view? Is my understanding of the equivalence principle wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going straight to words such as "inertia" it may be helpful to focus your thought first of all on the equivalence principle. This comes in two forms, commonly called "weak equivalence principle" and "strong equivalence principle". The weak equivalence principle is best stated (IMO) as a statement about universality of acceleration under gravity. It is the statement that in any given gravitational field all bodies have the same acceleration under gravity alone. (In more technical language, they have the same worldline). The strong equivalence principle extends this. It is the observation that in the limit of a small region of spacetime all physical effects tend to the ones you would get in flat spacetime (i.e. the physics of special relativity).

Notice, therefore, that the equivalence principle can be stated without explicitly mentioning the concept of inertia. You don't even need to mention any gravitational force!

Having said all that, when we observe an acceleration under gravity, it is convenient to multiply that acceleration by the inertial mass of the body that is accelerating, and thus get a "gravitational force". But you should ask yourself: accelerating relative to what? If our system of coordinates is itself in freefall (and the distances and times involved are small) then there won't be any acceleration of any freely falling object relative to that reference frame. So the only way to get an "acceleration due to gravity" (and hence a "force of gravity") is to employ a reference frame which is not in freefall. Thus the "force of gravity" does indeed turn out to have exactly the same character as an inertial force.

So the above description is basically agreeing with you. What D'Inverno is then pointing out is that in the case of flat spacetime you might as well say there is no gravity. So the physics is such that anyone can, if they want, insist that we only employ the term "gravity" for cases where spacetime is not flat.

The non-flat character of spacetime is revealed by things such as
geodesic deviation. That is a higher-order effect connected to spacetime curvature. The presence or absence of curvature at any event in spacetime is an objective property which can be measured. So if you like you can make a choice of *terminology* in which the term "inertial force" is reserved for the case where the local curvature is zero (i.e. we have flat spacetime) and the term "gravity" is reserved for the case where the local curvature is not zero. However that way of using the terminology has not caught on, so in the standard use of terms one may well say that  "gravitational force" is an inertial force, for the reason I gave above.

And of course the physical behaviours are what they are, independent of our use of terms.

Comment: I don't know if I totally agree with that phrasing of the equivalence principle. I understand it and it makes sense in hindsight. But I don't find good reason to say "in small regions of spacetime, all physical effects tend to the ones you would get in flat spacetime". That seems to imply curvature apriori, but we don't know that yet. It seems to just insert curvature into the problem arbitrarily. I did understand your terminology about reserving the name "gravity" to the case where curvature isn't zero. But I still don't understand the need to insert curvature in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to the principle of equivalence I want to get the following out of the way: the expression 'inertial force' is awkward.

The idea of 'force' is that you have *two* objects exerting a force *upon each other*. (You can have assemblies of multiple objects, of course, it's just that *two* objects is the minimum.)

Among the simplest examples of force would be the Coulomb force between, say, two protons.

**Third law force pair**

One way to demarcate the extent of the concept of force is to use Newton's third law as definition. It is a force when it can be described as a third law force pair.

Inertia cannot be categorized as a force, because inertia is about a *single* object. For a single object: a force is required to cause change of velocity. For inertia the idea of a third law force pair is not applicable.

If inertia would be a counterforce in the sense of Newton's third law then motion would be impossible; every force would be countered by an equal and opposite force. Inertia opposes change of velocity, but does not prevent it.

Inertia is like [inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance). (Self-)inductance manifests itself as opposition to *change* of current strength. At the same time: (self-)inductance cannot *prevent* change of current strength. The inductance mechanism of opposition to change of current strength is that an electromagnetic response is elicited by *change of current strength*. So it is inherently impossible for (self-)inductance to prevent change. Instead change is opposed; the stronger the (self-)inductance, the slower the change of current strength. In the case of Inertia: Inertia offers opposition to change of velocity, but does not prevent it.

Summerizing:
Inertia is in a category of it's own.
Any attempt to think of inertia in terms of force leads to self-contradiction.

**The Principle of Equivalence**

To set the stage of for the principle of equivalence I will discuss some aspects of Maxwell's concept of the electromagnetic Aether. Of course, Maxwell's Aether is a thing of the past, but in its time it served Maxwell purposes well. The reasons why it served Maxwell's purposes are interesting, and relevant.

The problem that Maxwell faced was: how to concieve of an entity that combines the following capabilities: it must have the capacity to act as the mediator of the electromagnetic interaction, *and* it must support propagation of electromagnetic waves.

What Maxwell conveived was an entity that is omnipresent in space. This omnipresent entity has a null state, in that null state Maxwell's Aether is in a uniform state. In that uniform state Maxwell's Aether does not affect motion of an electric charge moving through it at uniform velocity.

Next: Presence of a *source* of Coulomb force induces a stressed state in Maxwell's Aether. While the uniform state does not affect motion of electric charge, the stressed state does. This state of stress is then acting as the mediator of electromagnetic interaction. The distribution of the stressed state is then referred to as 'the electromagnetic field'.

Maxwell concieved of this Aether to have an extremely strong tendency to return to the uniform state. Also, rate of change of the state would tend to persist.

Oscillation has the following two requirements:
-Tendency to return to a particular state (generally designated as 'state of lowest potential energy)
-A property that a *rate of change* of the state tends to persist. (This tendency is generally designated as 'kinetic energy')

That is how Maxwell's Aether supports propagation of electromagnetic waves.

That is a very rough outlone of how Maxwell solved the problem of concieving of a *single entity* that acts as mediator of electromagnetic interaction, and supports propagation of electromagnetic waves.

**Inertia and gravity**

In the case of inertia and gravity we have the following problem:
Can we conceive of an entity that does both of the following things:
-Act as the mediator of gravitational interaction
-Accommodate the equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass

Einstein's expressed his solution to the above problem in the form of the principle of equivalence.

Inertia is omnipresent in the universe. Inertia is assumed to be perfectly uniform. Inertia does not affect the motion of objects in uniform motion.

Assume that a source of gravitational interaction induces a *stressed state* in the omnipresent inertia. This stressed state is then thought of as introducing a *bias* in the normally uniform inertia. This stressed state is then acting as the mediator of gravitational interaction.

Prior to the introduction of GR the phenomena of inertia and gravity were thought of as separate entities.

GR introduced a fundamental unification.
John Stachel, director of the centre for Einstein studies, proposed in the 1990's the following name for the field that is described with the Einstein Field Equations: The inertio-gravitational field

The name 'theory of the inertio-gravitational field' makes everything fall into place. In that sense it's too bad it hasn't yet found wide adoption.

Example of a recent article in which the name 'inertio-gravitational field is used:
Dennis Lehmkuhl:
'Why Einstein did not believe that General Relativity geometrizes gravity' (PDF-document, 231 KB) [Download](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1355219813000695) from sciencedirect.com (no paywall) (also available for [download](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9825/) from [PhilSciArchive](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/))

**Inertia and geometry**

Prior to the introduction of relativistic physics it was assumed that the phenomenon of Inertia has the same symmetries and uniformity as Euclidean space.

The introduction of Special Relativity modified that view as follows:
In terms of Special Relativity Inertia has the same symmetries and uniformity as Minkowski spacetime.

The point is: there is no *experiment* that can distinguish between the properties of Inertia and the properties of spacetime.

In physics there is the following rule of thumb:
If no experiment exists that can distinguish between A and B then it makes no sense to formulate a theory in which A and B are treated as distinct. Instead: treat A and B as one and the same.

In terms of special relativity no distinction is made between the properties of inertia and the properties of Minkowski spacetime; no experiment exists that can distinguish between the two.

Finally: about gravitational waves (the waves detected by the LIGO experiment)

It took the physics community many decades to work out whether GR implies that the inertio-gravitational field also supports *propagation of gravitational waves*.

The detection of gravitaional waves corroborates the view that gravitational interaction is mediated by a *stressed state* of the inertio-gravitational field.

In the case of gravitational waves there is an oscillation of stressed state, carrying energy.

Comment: Would using the term "pseudo force" be more suitable? What I mean by it in any case is an apparent acceleration that arises due to a particular choice of coordinate systems and has nothing to do with the particle itself like the Coriolis effect. The way I understand the equivalence principle is that gravity is such an effect. It can be viewed as arising from a choice of coordinate. What I don't understand is the need to distinguish it from those effects by masking the spacetime metric curved if the principle states their equivalence.

Comment: I don't quite understand this way if thinking about inertia and gravity or about Maxwell's electromagnetism. In the null state, Maxwell's Aether does not affect motion of an electric charge moving through it at uniform velocity. Isn't that charge a source of Coulomb force? Doesn't that make the null state impossible to achieve? Same for gravity, since it's given the same treatment. And I don't see the "equivalence" in this formulation of the EP. If gravity is inducing stress in the uniform inertia, where's the equivalence? It's between what and what exactly?

Comment: @EM_1 The term 'pseudo force' is equally problematic. The concept of force correlates with interaction. In theory of motion: Interaction is that objects exert a force upon each other, altering each other's direction and/or magnitude of velocity. In the process there is exchange of momentum. Inertia is the phenomenon that a force is required to change the velocity of an object. Inertia is not an interaction with another object.

Comment: @EM_1  I recommend that you let go of the word 'equivalence', you appear to be stuck somewhere. I recommend you approach the subject as a *unification*.  Example of unification: theory of *heat* and theory of motion were originally thought of as describing distinct phenomena. But at some point someone had the idea that heat can be described in terms of kinetic energy of atoms/molecules; unification. That is a discovery that theory of motion has a wider scope than physicists originally thought it had. GR offers *unification* of describing inertia and describing gravitational interaction.

Comment: @EM_1 I noticed something else I need to clarify.  A common concept in theory of motion is to speak of a 'test mass'. A test mass does have some gravitational mass, in the sense that its motion is affected by a gravitational field,  but in the thought demonstration it is so much less massive than the primary gravitational mass that the effect of the test mass on *other* objects is negligable. The 'test mass' serves as a probe. So, in terms of Maxwell's Aether: that would be a 'test charge', A test charge is then treated as so small that its own effect on other charged objects is negligable.

Answer (score -1):

Although there are similarities between gravity and inertia, I have always thought of these as simply happenstance.  The main difference between the two is, what I feel, the single most important aspect of gravity; its direct connection to time dilation.  You can imagine the incredible inertial force of a bullet in the barrel of a rifle; something like 4x10^5 m/s^2 which is getting darned close to the gravity near a black hole.  But there is no associated time dilation of the bullet. So while the equivalence principle is a good model, it is far from complete.

Comment: Follow up: How do we know there's no such thing as "inertial time dilation"?

Comment: Because I asked this exact question a few months ago: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709850/under-the-equivalence-principle-does-a-bullet-experience-gravitational-time-dil/709885#709885

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't add up. Take the standard thought experiment: A wheel shaped space station, at distance $r$ to the axis of rotation the ring is pulling 1 G. Take the stairs to one level closer to the axis and compare proper time. Closer to the axis is up the potential gradient, with a corresponding *difference* in amount of proper time that elapses. In order to measure difference in amount of proper time you must compare *two spatially separate locations*, up or down the potential gradient. (I just noticed the downvote; I concur with that downvote, but it wasn't me.)

Comment: @Cleonis take a look at the article mentioned in the other question about the clock postulate https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/clock.html   Acceleration in itself does not have an effect on clock rate; only the fact that the clock is moving faster at each point in time, which does cause time dilation.  So it is speed, not acceleration that leads to time dilation.  I assume this would be the situation on Discovery One.    Inertia is all about acceleration, not speed.  So this is the difference in the equivalence principle.

Comment: @Cleonis  I'm just looking at the other two answers. They do mention "curvature" but the fact is that on Earth, 99.9% of gravity is caused by the time dilation part of spacetime curvature.  It is only at a black hole that 50% of the curvature is cause by space curvature.  So, I feel, that to answer this question without direct discussion of time dilation is missing the most important part of comparing gravity to inertia.

Comment: You write: 'it is speed [...] that leads to time dilation'. Of course it is widely known that accumulated time dilation does not correlate with accumulated acceleration. Here's the thing: the *Minkowski metric* relates difference in amount of elapsed proper time to difference in spatial distance covered. The point is: the Minkowski metric is the *direct* expression. From there we have indirect connection to velocity through the fact that velocity is the derivative of position with respect to time. In terms of the Minkowski metric: what *counts* is difference in spatial distance covered.

Comment: Take a look at the following article by Andrew Hamilton and and Jason Lisle: [The river model of black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060) (For emphasis: that article does not present a new theory. Hamilton and Lisle point out that in GR no self-contradiction arises when difference in amount of elapsed proper time is expressed in terms of difference in spatial distance covered. This embodies that GR unifies gravitational time dilation and velocity time dilation. I get the impression that you are way underestimating the depth of GR. )